# AttributeError: psutil has no attribute 'dirty'

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, cpu-usage, psutil

[image]Hello guys I am working on a python3 migration project in which I have upgraded psutil version to 5.9.0

here is a snippet of my code

```
import psutil
mem = psutil.virtual_memory()
x.add_metric(schema.yy_MEMORY_DIRTY, mem.dirty)
```

but in this getting AttributeError: psutil has no attribute 'dirty'
whereas it is working fine in psutil version 5.6.6